# How can I get the size of a component when using a layout for my frame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jcomponent

How can I get the size of a component when using a layout for my frame?
I can just note that I'm using a BorderLayout for a JFrame and I want the size of a JPanel.

Comment: Why do you need the size? Unless we know the requirement we can't make a suggestion.

Comment: The [preferred size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) is determined by the content and layout of the enclosing container.

Comment: @camickr
I want to override the paint function to draw a grid on it. And I don't know how many lines to draw, and how long the lines should be. I don't want my class to be limited to manually designed frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `JPanel` methods, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`:

```
int getWidth();
int getHeight();
```

They will return the height and width of the `JPanel`.

You can also get the bounds of the `JPanel` using the method `getBounds()`:

```
Rectangle getBounds();
```

It will return a `Rectangle` of the bounds. You can use it to get the location and size of the `JPanel`.

Comment: When the panel is placed in a frame using a layout, all the mentioned functions will return 0.

Comment: you are getting 0 because you calling the methods before your main frame is render. the above method is work only when you call after the setVisible();
or you can try pack() method.